# Azure Devops Build Pipeline failure for Publish Artifacts

Tags: build, azure-devops, artifact

We have a Publish Artifact step in a build pipeline which has been working consistently for a long period. This last week the Publish Artifact step now fails to upload with a disk space error:

> Fail to upload 'D:\agent_work\15\a\NO_Trunk_390_DeployFiles.zip' due to 'There is not enough space on the disk.'.
> System.IO.IOException: There is not enough space on the disk.
> at System.IO.Compression.DeflateStream.WriteDeflaterOutputAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at System.IO.Compression.DeflateStream.WriteAsyncMemoryCore(ReadOnlyMemory`1 buffer, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at System.IO.Stream.CopyToAsyncInternal(Stream destination, Int32 bufferSize, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.FileContainer.Client.FileContainerHttpClient.UploadFileAsync(Int64 containerId, String itemPath, Stream fileStream, Guid scopeIdentifier, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Int32 chunkSize, Boolean uploadFirstChunk, Object userState, Boolean compressStream)
> at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.Worker.Build.FileContainerServer.UploadAsync(IAsyncCommandContext context, Int32 uploaderId, CancellationToken token)

The step is set up to publish to Azure Pipelines rather than to a file share.
In an attempt to make some space I've deleted old builds, assuming this would also delete the artifacts from them, but this hasn't made any difference.

Is there a way to view the disk usage from VSTS and manually delete items?

Comment: Do you use Azure DevOps services or server?

Comment: did you check linked to disk space on the server.

Comment: What agent are you using? Microsoft-hosted agent or self-hosted agent? Do you have the same issue if you use another type of agent?

Comment: Hi friend, is there any update for this issue?  Would you please share your latest information about this issue?